# Decoding email Message Id <>

Tags: email

As part of an assignment I have been given a series of email headers to analyse.

I am having trouble with the email Message ID.

If anyone can be of assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

The message id is...

trinity-da74042a-7db7-40e7-b72f-f8b8077653b1-1458404301335@3capp-mailcom-lxa15

I know the RHS part after @ is the FQDN (3capp-mailcom-lxa15), but if anyone could help shed some light on the first 6 blocks on the LHS.

Thank you.

G.

Answer (score 1):

The part between `trinity-` and `@` is [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). `trinity-` is probably some fixed (or 'fixed') string, like a hostname of the system, or the name of the MTA.